Serge Lang's Definition of a Free Group
Serge Lang says the following in his "Algebra":

We now consider the category $\mathfrak{C}$ whose objects are the maps of $S$ into groups. If $f:S\rightarrow G$ and $f':S\rightarrow G'$ are two objects in $\mathfrak{C}$, we define a morphism from $f$ to $f'$ to be a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow G'$ such that $\varphi\circ f=f'$. By a free group determined by $S$ we mean a universal element in this category.

My understanding of a universal element is as follows. Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a category and $\mathfrak{f}:\mathfrak{C}\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}$ be a covariant functor into the category of sets. Let $\mathfrak{C}_\mathfrak{f}$ be the category in which $Ob(\mathfrak{C}_\mathfrak{f})$ consists of all pairs $(C,x)$, where $C$ is an object in $\mathfrak{C}$ and $x$ is an element of the set $\mathfrak{f}(C)$. A morphism in $\mathfrak{C}_\mathfrak{f}$ from $(C,x)$ to $(D,y)$ is defined to be a morphism $f:C\rightarrow D$ in $\mathfrak{C}$ such that $\mathfrak{f}(f)(x)=y$, where $y$ is an element of the set $\mathfrak{f}(D)$. A universal object in $\mathfrak{C}_\mathfrak{f}$ is said to be a universal element of the functor $\mathfrak{f}$.
Given this, I do not see how a free group is a universal element in the category of whose objects are the maps of $S$ into groups. I have two questions:

Is my understanding of what a universal element is correct?
How do I see that a free group is a universal element in the said category?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

From where is that excerpted? Please add a citation to the question (not in a comment).

Firstly Lang is ever so slightly sloppy here. They don't just mean a universal object, they specifically mean an initial object. "Universal object" tends to allow either initial or terminal, context-dependent.
Lang said "universal element" here but in your language, they mean a universal object of the category $\mathfrak{C}$. However, we can set this up to be a true "universal element" problem; their category $\mathfrak{C}$ could be construed as $\mathrm{el}(\mathfrak{f})$ where $\mathfrak{f}_S:\mathscr{G}\to\mathfrak{S}$ is the functor $G\mapsto\hom_{\mathfrak{S}}(S,U(G))$ where $U$ is the forgetful functor from groups to sets; then a free group "on $S$" is exactly a universal (well, initial) element for $\mathfrak{f}_S$. I don't recommend all these fancy fonts but I'm using your style; ideally we just write $\mathsf{Set}$ for set and $\mathsf{Grp}$ for groups, something clear along those lines.
As for why free groups have this property, I recommend you just directly check from the definition. Check that homomorphisms $F(S)\to G$ are entirely determined by the underlying function $f:S\to G$ on the canonical generating elements. This is very well known and I don't want to duplicate that here. Look up "(universal) mapping property of free groups".

Thank you for your answer! Most of it is clear to me, but I do have one more question. The objects of the category $\mathfrak{C}$ as per what Lang says consists of maps, whence a universal (initial) object in $\mathfrak{C}$ is a map $f:S\rightarrow G$. How is this is a free group a universal object in $\mathfrak{C}$ as you say it is?

@AravindGundakaram An initial $a:S\to FS$ is exactly a function such that for all other functions $b:S\to G$ there exists a unique homomorphism $f:FS\to G$ with $fa=b$. Free groups have the mapping property that group homomorphisms out of them are uniquely determined by their values on the canonical generators i.e. uniquely determined by an equation of type $fa=b$, if we think of $a(s)$ as the canonical generator associated to $s$. As long as you know this mapping property you know free groups - as defined otherwise - always exist and satisfy the initial object condition

Understood fully and accepted answer. Thanks!
